# As a developer, when should I test my website?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, cross-browser, web

After I release my website I want to test it in a few browsers. Also, when a new Android device comes out I'll take a look there also. I'm curious about what other milestones I should use to guide my website testing schedule (for example, when a new version of Chrome is launched should I make it a priority to test in that new version?)

Just as background: My site has high quality requirements and needs to work in a lot of different browsers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: common sense. when something new come out if youre concerned about it, test it. but a lot of browsers use the same JS engines and stuff so different devices don't necessarily mean different browser

Comment: use some online website that give hundred of screenshot in different environment.

Answer (score 0):

in the end it's all about the money. every new browser/device is expected to get some share of the market. based on that you can calculate how much money you will loose if this device/browser doesn't render your page correctly. you also know how much you have to pay keep track of new browser/devices and testing them (often in beta version)

i don't think there are any other guidelines. you monitor the market and decide which browsers/devices you want to support. if it's critical it's smart to make tests also on beta versions (that tells you what to expect, how much time to schedule on final tests and fixes)

Answer (score 0):

It's very rare to get website broken in new version of chrome/Firefox.

```
when a new Android device comes out I'll take a look there also
```

Do you means when new version of android come or new popular device released.

All browser have same browser and all work same. Again it's hard to get site broken in new version of android.

For testing you can get many screenshot of your site in different environment online. I have used it and it's work well for testing.

For example your site broke in Opera you can easily fix it by seeing issue in screenshot.